# Most optimal way to store reusable contract strings

Tags: solidity, gas

I'm just starting out with solidity and right from the gecko am met with several ways to store strings i.e

```
    string _data = "MyString";

    string private _data = "MyString";

    string internal _data = "MyString";

    bytes8 private constant = "MyString";
```

And various combinations of above. I am trying to understand how these affect gas costs and so far am pretty confident that

1. Using `bytesX` is better than `string` where possible
2. Adding `constant` is better when value won't be changing
3. Using `private` is better than `internal` if this value is accessible only in this contract

I wanted to ask if my assumptions above are correct, if same applies to arrays i.e. `bytes8[2] = ["MyString", "XyString"]` and is there anything else I need to be aware of i.e. when to use `memory`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference can be explained by how the compiler implement those types.

`bytesNN` is fixed sequence of NN bytes while `string` is a dynamic array of bytes. Using `string` increases the runtime bytecode due to a few auxiliary function included by the compiler.

For a `public` variable the compiler has to create a getter function.

A `constant` declaration will be inlined by the compiler, it will not use storage.

For example `bytes8[2]` is a fixed array of 2 `bytes8`.

Comment: Could you please expand on constant? As I am not really getting it, it will still be accessible i.e. if I say save some string to re-use latter, so I assume it has to be stored?

Comment: @Ilja A constant string will continue working as a string as it is expected. It will not use storage slots, it will be stored together with the contract bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose the more restrictive it is, the more it is efficient, hence the reason why private would be more efficient than internal ?

EDIT : i mean the resulted code once compiled would be more efficient, at least that's what i'm thinking and makes sense to me, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: It is not how narrow the scope it is but how it is implemented by the compiler.